# Can band start a WP application or is a background task able to handle band notifications?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, microsoft-band

assume I have a tile on my Microsoft Band (2) and want to record the current HB when the user presses my tile (or a button on a screen).
Just something like cortana does - trigger anything on the band - cortana is started on the device handling the request.

I found nothing about such a scenario in the (poor) SDK documentation.
Is such a solution possible - or do I always have to have my app in foreground on the phone (WP10)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be notified of Tile events (such as button presses), your application *must* (1) be running in the foreground or background, (2) have an outstanding connection to the Band, and (3) be subscribed to those specific events.  There is currently no way (on Windows) to otherwise notify an application of input from the Band.

Comment: Thank you Phil - is there a sample for a background app responding to band events?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  There's really no difference between using the Band in the foreground or the background.  The thing to remember is that background tasks run at most every ~30 minutes (on Windows Phone) and are granted a limited amount of CPU time, so you can't just keep a connection to the Band open for an extended period of time waiting for occasional input from the Band.

Comment: What about DeviceUseTrigger for this case? Bur I guess even if this is possible it wouldn't help much since API access is very limited background task.Too bad MSFT is so restricted in mobile apps. Just (a simple example) - in AW it's no problem to write a app which - on the touch of a button can push the current position to a web service. Or (another example which I have working on a "UWP phone app" - hit a button to turn on a light (AllJoyn). No prob. with a UWP app (and also in AW - but impossible with the Band. Even if I have the "partner app" running on the phone lock screen will end it

Comment: DeviceUseTrigger cannot be used with the Band (as far as I know).  Yes, the Windows platform has traditionally made ad-hoc triggering of applications via devices challenging (but admittedly with good intentions, for reasons related to both security and battery life).  Windows 10 does bring new platform features that makes such scenarios theoretically possible, but that likely still requires updates to the Band firmware, the Microsoft Health application, and the SDK.  (And I have no idea if or when that might happen.)

Comment: Hi - yes a lot of things are not possible at the MS (mobile) plattform - with good intentions. The road to hell is paved with good intentions :) Anyhow I found this http://jamescroft.co.uk/blog/iot/developing-for-microsoft-band-with-winrt-indefinite-background-execution/ BUT (even if it works) doesn't solve the general problem at all. Assume several tiles on your band which want to do something  - all need an app on the device running (or in background) - and here we are - one app running at the same time. it would be possible if the band could launch the matiching app (like Cortana does)

Comment: Thank you Phil - good to see that MSFT is present here. From my point of view the band is ATM not really usefull for anything else than beeing a fitness tracker. I wanted it as replacement for my android watch. Checking the store there are 5 (or so) apps for the band... Of course not more because how shall this work? Take out my phone, start the app - AFTER that use the band... If I allready have my phone working - why should i use the band? Notifications - OK - but what else except fitness?. Start / interact / close initiated from the band could change this